# Confusing git conflicts

Tags: git, bitbucket

Hi I really don't understand why git say this is a conflict.

Do you have any idea?

[image]

Comment: Seems like merging issue, try to remove these lines and it will work.

Comment: I see. I know how to solve the conflict. I just try to understand why git saying this is conflict, what is behind the scene.

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts  Hope this will help you to understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the line was:

- **deleted** in integrate branch
- **modified** in `feature/xxx` branch

Git cannot chose automatically which action to apply for that line, hence the conflict for you to resolve:

- delete
- or keep the line from `feature/xxx`.